# State isn't changing unless I refresh the page in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm using json server to get and post data. When I update data on server and go back to homescreen. It still shows old data unless I refresh the page. My useEffect is getting called. But why it is not updating state? Added a gif so one can get an idea of my problem.

[image: Gif]

**Note.js (HomeScreen)**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
//import notes from '../assets/data'
import Listitem from "../components/Listitem";
// import AddButton from "../components/AddButton";

const Notes = () => {
  let [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes();
  }, []);

  let getNotes = async () => {
      let response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/notes/");
      let data = await response.json();
      setNotes(data);
    };
console.log("called");
  return (
    <div className="notes">
      <div className="notes-header">
        <h2 className="notes-title">&#9782; Notes</h2>
        <p className="notes-count">{notes.length}</p>
      </div>

      <div className="notes-list">
        {notes.map((note, index) => (
          <Listitem key={index} note={note} />
        ))}
      </div>

      {/* <AddButton /> */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Notes;
```

**NotePage.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { ReactComponent as ArrowLeft } from "../assets/arrow-left.svg";
const NotePage = ({ match, history }) => {
  let noteId = match.params.id;
  //   const note = notes.find((c) => c.id == noteId);
  const [note, setNote] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getNote();
  }, [noteId]);

  let getNote = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/notes/${noteId}`);
    let data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    setNote(data);
  };

  let updateNote = async () => {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/notes/${noteId}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ ...note, updated: new Date() }),
    });
  };

  let handleSubmit = () => {
    updateNote();
    history.push("/");
  };

  console.log("again");
  return (
    <div className="note">
      <div className="note-header">
        <h3>
          <Link to="/">
            <ArrowLeft onClick={handleSubmit} />
          </Link>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <textarea
        onChange={(e) => setNote({ ...note, body: e.target.value })}
        value={note?.body}
      ></textarea>
      {/* <textarea>{note}</textarea> */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NotePage;
```

**List Item**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
const Listitem = ({ note }) => {
  return (
    <Link to={`/note/${note.id}`}>
      <div className="notes-list-item">
        <h3>{note.body}</h3>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import "./App.css";
import NotesPage from "./pages/NotesPage";
import NotePage from "./pages/NotePage";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container dark">
        <div className="app">
          <Header />
          <Route component={NotesPage} path="/" exact />
          <Route component={NotePage} path="/note/:id" exact />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You need to update the note list from the updated note, or fetch the list again when navigating.

Comment: What's the relationship between Note.js and NotePage.js? Is one a child of the other? Can you provide the code calling these components?

Comment: @ConnorLow updated the post. I'm getting data from json server in homescreen. When I click on any item. I get that specific item in notepage.js. I can update the data in json server within notepage.js on clicking back button.  But it doesnt update homscreen unless I refresh.

Comment: Looks like it might be a race condition, i.e. you are sending the request (PUT) to update your note but do not wait for the update to complete before returning to the home page. The home page then requests the notes list, again *before* the prior PUT request finishes. Try awaiting `updateNote()` before calling `history.push("/")` (e.g. by using `.then()`).

Comment: didnt work. Or its probably onChange that is working really slow. Sometimes it updates if I add a single alphabet and some times it doesnt.

Answer (score 2):

The code block inside `useEffect` gets called when 1. The Component is mounted (First created) 2. When values inside the dependency array change

Currently there is nothing in the dependency array, meaning the code inside of the `useEffect` hook will only execute when the component is mounted. Which in this case only when you reload the page.

Comment: I cannot pass note as dependancy as it will do infinite loop. What can be a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Has this been solved?

```
const slug = route.params.slug;

  const [product, setProduct] = useState('');
  
  const getProduct = async () => {
    try {
      const resp = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/products/${slug}`);
      const product = await resp.json();
      return setProduct(product);
    } catch (error) {
       console.error(error);
    }
    
  }
  useEffect(() => getProduct(), [slug]);
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33030812)